# Authenticate users using client MAC address?

Tags: iphone, web, mac-address

This question is not language-aware.

I wanna know how can I recognize a returning user on my website (Java, PHP, Coldfusion...) if he's using a dynamic IP.

Why? A lot of users of my web application use iPhone (with 3G networking) for accessing. IP changes each time, so I always see them as "new" users.

I know it's unlikely to track MAC address in web pages but.... what solutions are there for such a common problem?

Maybe a suitable iPhone app? ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not quite possible to find original requesting machine's MAC address. You should use Cookies to track users.

You can find more info about MAC Addresses [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address).

> A Media Access Control address (MAC address) is a unique identifier
>   assigned to network interfaces for communications on the physical
>   network segment. MAC addresses are used for numerous network
>   technologies and most IEEE 802 network technologies, including
>   Ethernet. Logically, MAC addresses are used in the Media Access
>   Control protocol sub-layer of the OSI reference model.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do what everybody else does and use cookies?

Answer (score 0):

As other said, you could easier get what you want with cookies...

and, reading your question and purpose, i'm not really sure that if a user uses it's iPhone via wifi and browse to your website and than it come back again via 3G the MAC address doesn't change... i thought that MAC address is unique not for a device, but for a single hardware component in it: this mean that an iPhone could have a MAC for wifi hardware and a MAC for 3g hardware... if it works as on my powerMac... i can see my computer has a mac address for my ethernet and one other for my wifi...

but i'm not an hardware expert, so (all readers), please consider this answer as a question too, and if there is any net expert on line...